# Using greater than in awk ( >) to compare two fields

Tags: awk

I'm trying to do something like

```
awk '/$2>$1/{print}'
```

But I'm getting no results,almost all of the second field though should be greater than the first field

Comment: Read here about http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You need to include some data  to make this an on-topic Q. Good luck.

Comment: Dropping the / s worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment by @kevin is correct: the `/` delimiters make the comparison a regular expression.

Given input

```
1 2
2 3
2 1
3 2
3 1
```

this

```
awk '$2>$1{print}'
```

gives

```
1 2
2 3
```